# Draw multiple charts with Flot, html, PHP and MySql query

Tags: php, mysql, html, charts, flot

I’m trying to draw multiple charts with Flot, html, PHP and MySql query but I’m stuck because I can’t find a way in order to draw multiple flots in the same html page.
In the database (test_db3) image for simplicity the following fields:

- table1(user_name, mail_sent, time)
- table2(user_name2, mail_received,time2)

those two tables cannot be modify, I can’t add the user_name2 to the table1 and so on.
in table1 are stored the values of the sent mail based on the time of sent
in table2 are stored the values of the received mail based on the time of reception

Before this code, I’ve tested the data stored in the DB with another code written previously it could only draw  2 charts of one user, but the data and the charts where correctly draw.
Now that I'm trying to draw 2 charts for all the users of the DB I’m stuck!
if necessary I can post the first code that extracts the data from the DB for a single user.
If anyone has any advice … thanks!

```
<html>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<?php
/*
connection to the database
*/
    $server = "localhost";
    $user="xxxxxx";
    $password=" xxxxxx ";  
    $database = "test_db3";
    $connection = mysql_connect($server,$user,$password) or die (mysql_error());       
    $db = mysql_select_db($database,$connection) or die (mysql_error());

    //The first Sql query is searching for DISTINCT users in the DB
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT user_name FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON user_name=user_name2")  or die(mysql_error()); 

    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
        { 
            $user = $info['user_name']; //It’s the name of user analyzed at the moment
            /*
            This query extract the first ten more recents values (order by time DESC)
            The data retrieved by the query are used to paint the 1° chart for emails sent by the user
            but I don't know how to do it recursively
            */
            $query = "SELECT user_name,mail_sent,time FROM table1 WHERE user_name='$user' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 0,10";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    $row['time']=$row['time']*1000; //The time is in millisecond I need to multiply for 1000 in order to obtain the seconds
                     //the 'time'  row is the x-axis , the 'mail_send' row is the y-axsis
                    $dataset1[] = array($row['time'],$row['mail_sent']); //It contains the time value and the numbers of email sent from the user
                 }

            /*
            This query extract the first ten more recents values (order by time2 DESC)
            The data retrieved by the query are used to paint the 2° chart for emails received by the user
            but I don't know how to do it recursively
            */
            $query2 = "SELECT user_name2,mail_received ,time2 FROM table2 WHERE user_name2='$user' ORDER BY time2 DESC LIMIT 0,10";
            $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
            while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
                {
                    $row2['time2']=$row2['time2']*1000; //The time is in millisecond I need to multiply for 1000 in order to obtain the seconds
                    //the 'time'  row is the x-axis , the 'mail_send' row is the y-axsis
                    $dataset2[] = array($row2['time2'],$row2['mail_received ']); //It contains the time value and the numbers of email received from the user
                 }
                    /*
                    Here I should insert some code in order to draw 2 charts for all the users of the DB, so for example if the DB has 30 Users
                    i need to draw 60 charts, 2 charts for any users
                    -> the 1° charts represents the mail sent from the user 
                    -> the 2° charts represents the mail received from the user
                    */
        } 
    mysql_close($connection); //Close connection DB  
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
// setup plot
    var options = {
        series: {
            lines: { show: true },
            points: { show: true }
                },
        //the value of min:0 and max:100 are just examples of course
        yaxis: { min: 0, max: 100 },

        xaxis: {
        mode: "time",
        minTickSize: [1, "minute"],

                }

    };

    var dataset1 = <?php echo json_encode($dataset1); ?>;
    var dataset2 = <?php echo json_encode($dataset2); ?>; 


    //This part is not correct because the palaceholder should have a increment value
    //placeholder0, placeholder1, placeholder3, placeholder4, ..., placeholderN
    //And it is necessary to place a <div id="placeholderN" style="width:350px;height:200px;"> </div> in the PHP code for every placeholder generated
    //or find another solution

    var plot1 = $.plot($(placeholder0), [ dataset1, dataset2 ], options); //For the 1° charts
    var plot2 = $.plot($(placeholder1), [ dataset1, dataset2 ], options); //Fot the 2° charts

    });//End script
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all it seems a little strange to have user_name2,time2,etc. for the second query.  Is that really how it's set up in your DB?

Anyway, here is one way to generate plots from within your PHP loops.

```
    echo('<div id="placeholder"></div>');
    echo('<script>');
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
        { 
            $user = $info['user_name']; //It’s the name of user analyzed at the moment
            /*
            This query extract the first ten more recents values (order by time DESC)
            The data retrieved by the query are used to paint the 1° chart for emails sent by the user
            but I don't know how to do it recursively
            */
            $query = "SELECT user_name,mail_sent,mail_received,time FROM table1 WHERE user_name='$user' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 0,10";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            $dataset1 = new Array();
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    $row['time']=$row['time']*1000; //The time is in millisecond I need to multiply for 1000 in order to obtain the seconds
                     //the 'time'  row is the x-axis , the 'mail_send' row is the y-axsis
                    $dataset1[] = array($row['time'],$row['mail_sent']); //It contains the time value and the numbers of email sent from the user
                 }
            echo('$.plot( $(\'<div style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>\').appendTo(\'#placeholder\'),'.json_encode($dataset1).',options);\n');
        }
    echo('</script>');
```