# Paint more than one flot in a page

Tags: php, mysql, html, ajax, flot

Could be possible to post some code examples on how to use Flot with PHP and MySql in order to draw more than one graph in a html page? 
ex. -> Extract data from DB and paint two o more flots from them with a while loop

Answer (score 4):

Since flot is already not coupled to the div it is plotting into, multiple plots should be as easy as single plots:

```
<div id="plot1"></div>
<div id="plot2"></div>

....
//some script fragment
$.plot($('#plot1'), dataFor1, options);
$.plot($('#plot2'), dataFor2, options);
```

Comment: Yeah, I've done up to 10 graphs on the same page with no problems.

Answer (score 2):

Is this related to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9439831/1236211)?

If you'll be creating plots within loops, you may find it easier to do something like this:

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
     $.plot( $('<div style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>').appendTo('#placeholder'),data[i],options);
```

If you initialize the plots in that way, you don't need to make the divs in advance.